# MathJax buttons/hotkeys script

Tags: discussion

I've written a script that lets you insert dollar symbols automatically(via a keyboard shortcut or button) in the editor window on Stack Exchange sites that support MathJax. Feel free to check it out.

[Installation instructions and details here](https://stackapps.com/questions/3373/mathjax-buttons)